# How to convert a Icon to Bitmap in android?

Tags: android, bitmap, icons

I want to convert a Icon to Bitmap object in android.

My goal is to convert from Notification Icon to bitmap.

What should i do??

Thank you for all the answers!

Comment: Thanks all. I solved with Reflection method(loadDrawableInner).

Comment: I don't think this question is a complete duplicate, although similar. The difference is that `Icon` is not a `Drawable` but you can get a `Drawable` from an `Icon` using: `icon.loadDrawable(context)`

Comment: Use this code :  
        Icon icon = notification.getSmallIcon();
        Bitmap bitmap = icon.loadDrawable(context);

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps

```
Bitmap bitmapIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but, I want to convert a Icon in Notification Object to bitmap.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this class. Also I usually use this code.

```
public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
Bitmap bitmap = null;

if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
    if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
        return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
    }
}

if(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
} else {
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
}

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
drawable.draw(canvas);
return bitmap;
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but, Notification.getSmallIcon() returns not Drawable but Icon object...